# How do HTMLCollections work? Can I create my own HTMLCollection?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on javascript serialization library that will allow me to serialize parts of DOM. In DOM operations, we often use HTMLCollections. Now HTMLCollection isn't just an ordinary array:

```
var collection = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
console.log(collection.length);
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));
console.log(collection.length);
```

This outputs:

[image: image description]

Obviously not an ordinary array. Obviously, it's a matching rule on dom element that updates the list every time element child node list changes. On that, I have two questions:

1. Can I reliably serialize `HTMLCollection` not as a list of elements, but as a **matching rule it represents**?
2. Can I create `HTMLCollection` that **is instance** of `HTMLCollection` and follows my **own matching rule**, without having to re-implement the algorithm that decides when to re-update the list?

Comment: `HTMLCollection` appear to be `readonly` . What is expected result ? What is _" own matching rule"_ ?

Comment: @guest271314 Complex rule, such as *... all elements that contain words "a guy with no imagination"...* or something like that.

Comment: If element has `name` or `id` attribute set to `"a guy with no imagination"` could use `element = collection.namedItem("a guy with no imagination")` or 
`element = collection["a guy with no imagination"]` , though converting to `Array` and using `Array.prototype.filter()` could also be an option ? See http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#interface-htmlcollection

Comment: serialize to what format? and when? Not clear what you are needing

Comment: @guest271314 This wouldn't update in a way collection does, also I meant node text contets, not ID.

Comment: @charlietfl Why the hell does format matter to you? I mean once I have needed data, I can serialize whatever I want to, be it QR code if I decide... The important thing is that I need to **get information that defines a collection** then **re-create it using the information** I got.

Comment: sounds a bit like you are wanting something based on MutationObservers

Comment: @charlietfl that would be it, but as I **specified in the question**: "*without having to re-implement the algorithm that decides when to re-update the list?*. I could re-implement the behavior in 10 minutes, but I'm convinced native implementation is way faster.

Comment: @TomášZato _"This wouldn't update in a way collection does"_ What would not update ? If used `.filter()` to select elements with certain text , change text , then call `HTMLCollection` , the `HTMLCollection` would be updated as it is live _"An HTMLCollection in the HTML DOM is live; it is automatically updated when the underlying document is changed."_ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection . _"also I meant node text contets, not ID"_ Not appear to be possible to select item in `HTMLCollection` with text of element

Comment: _"as I specified in the question: "without having to re-implement the algorithm that decides when to re-update the list?"_ The `HTMLCollection` is updated when `DOM` is updated .